# how can i split a pandas dataframe by elements on a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe of persons and i want to split it by city("UF"), is there a better way to do it without specifying each city?

i tried this:

```
city_list = people["UF"].drop_duplicates()
temporary = []
for city in city_list:
    temporary.append(people[people["UF"] == city])
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the split? You might need `groupby`

Comment: it would be `groupby` or `pivot`....

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby function,

```
grouped_cities = people.groupby("UF")
temporary = [group for _, group in grouped_cities]
```